# Remove list of keys in object, the key may not exist

Tags: ramda.js

I have a object that *may* have some keys

```
const input = {
  whatsapp: "123",
  telegram: "bbb",
}
```

And I want to remove a list of **possible** keys:

```
const removeThis = ['whatsapp', 'telegram', 'signal', 'wechat']
```

Using Ramda, how can I remove all possible keys in the object `input`?

The key may not exist in the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `R.omit`:

```js
const input = {
  whatsapp: "123",
  telegram: "bbb",
  stay: 'xxx'
}

const removeThis = ['whatsapp', 'telegram', 'signal', 'wechat']

const result = R.omit(removeThis, input)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```